# converting hexa decimal ip address to dot notation decimal in c#

Tags: c#

I have an ip address column in which it is stored as varbinary(16) and the value is for eg:0x0A6D040D. I want to convert it into ip address format with dot notation.I am new to c#.Please help me

Comment: A `VARBINARY` should be retrieved as a `byte[]`, then you can use the constructor of `IPAddress` which accepts that. Getting the dotted notation from that is left as an exercise.

Comment: Do it by hand and then find out how you can make your computer do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the ip address as a byte array. Then create a new [`System.Net.IPAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress?view=netframework-4.7.2) to easily convert to your dot-notation.

```
byte[] ipArray = { 0x0A, 0x6D, 0x04, 0x0D }; // fetch from DB as byte[]
System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(ipArray);
String ipStr = ip.ToString(); // your dot-notation as String.
Console.WriteLine(ipStr);     // Output: "10.109.4.13"
```

DotnetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oAV3EF